# NSNotification Log statement repeats

Tags: ios, nsnotification

I'm creating an app but I'm having a bit of a problem, not a fatal error problem but a annoyance.
Basically my `NSNotification`s are staying around after my view is released
so when I bring my view back, lets say four times,
I have "this is your Notification" the amount of times I reloaded the view.  All other methods stay OK with `NSLog`s "this is a log statement."
Do I have to `release` or remove the NC after it is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to remove the observer.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

or

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer];
```

if `self` is not the observer